# How do I format my output as a 4-by-4 matrix?

Tags: java

```
class By
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
String key = "Hello world";// plaintext
byte[] x = key.getBytes();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
int b = (int) x[i];
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
This program output is: 48656c6c6f20776f726c64
I need my output to be a 4-by-4 matrix as such:
                      1st row is:: 48   6f   72   00
                      2nd row is:: 65   20   6c   00
                      3rd row is:: 6c   77   64   00
                      4th row is:: 6c   6f   00   00
```

How do I write code for this in java?Please anyone show me the code to get my required output.

Comment: This same question was literally just asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999956/how-to-get-hexadecimal-values-from-string-and-form-a-4-by-4-matrix.

Comment: I have seen just now.but no one did not give the code for this question.

Comment: The previous question was asked and formatted correctly.. now its back to 0

Comment: @devi no one will give the code, please make an attempt and post your results..If you were able to write this code then you should be able to print some \n in the  correct position.. try a few times and see what output you get.

Comment: I am not getting u sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
public class FourByFour {

    private List<String> hexlify(final String plaintext) {
        byte[] x = plaintext.getBytes();
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final byte aX : x) {
            int b = (int) aX;
            list.add(Integer.toHexString(b));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private void fourByFour(final List<String> hexString) {
        /*
            1st row is:: 48   6f   72   00
            2nd row is:: 65   20   6c   00
            3rd row is:: 6c   77   64   00
            4th row is:: 6c   6f   00   00
         */
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            for (int y = x; y < hexString.size(); y += 4) {
                System.out.print(hexString.get(y) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("00");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        final FourByFour fourByFour = new FourByFour();
        final List<String> hexString = fourByFour.hexlify("Hello World");
        fourByFour.fourByFour(hexString);
    }
}
```

outputs to:

```
hexString = [48, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f, 20, 57, 6f, 72, 6c, 64]
48 6f 72 00
65 20 6c 00
6c 57 64 00
6c 6f 00
```

I think you should be able to do the rest...